# I can't get genymotion to run my app

Tags: android, emulation, genymotion

I am using Android Studio, and I have the Genymotion plugin installed. When I click on the plugin, it opens the emulator without issue. However, when I attempt to run my app, the Genymotion emulator does not show up as an available option.

I searched for this problem before and no specific answer was given till now

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try restarting ADB.

`adb kill-server;adb start-server`

Comment: thanks a lot, I found this answer helpful too
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24948556/revisions)